# Disable hyperlink on one entry of the ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I want to disable hyperlink on *only one* entry of the table of contents.
Actually, I have added a line of text in the table, corresponding to no real section, so I don't want any internal link on this text…

I know there is specific macros to disable hyperlink on references, but I have found nothing about entries of the ToC ?

Here's a MWE :

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}
\appendix
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{Text that don't have to be clickable}{}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\chapter*`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use the original `\addtocontents` and `\contentsline` before `hyperref` transforms them to make hyperlinks possible -- those original versions are stored to `\orig...` using the `\let` primitive.

I've not used the `memoir` version right now.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\let\origcontentsline\contentsline
\let\origaddtocontents\addtocontents
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Chapter one}
\chapter{Chapter two}
\appendix
\origaddtocontents{toc}{\protect\origcontentsline{chapter}{Text that don't have to be clickable}{}}
\chapter{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

[image]