# Adding the word chapter to table of contents and keep hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, chapters

I know there are existing ways to add the word chapter like this:

[image: Frequently asked chapter option]

However, I want to group all the chapters under one chapter heading to look like this:

[image: What I want]

I can actually get this type of format with the code

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{multirow}

 \usepackage{fancyvrb}

 \usepackage{tabularx}

 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} 

 \usepackage{amsmath}

%  \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

  \listoffigures

  \listoftables

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{part}{\normalsize\textnormal{CHAPTER}}{}}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, for some reason, this isn't compatible with hyperref. It gets the error:

`./FinalDissertationManuscript.toc:5: Argument of \contentsline has an extra }. <inserted text> \par l.5 \contentsline {chapter}{\hspace *{30pt}\numberline {I} INTRODUCTION}{1}{...`

I've also tried the solution for disabling hyperref for an individual TOC entry found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301470/disable-hyperlink-on-one-entry-of-the-toc), but the error still exists.

Is there anyway to get the same output but still keep the hyperref package?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've updated the question with a more descriptive example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `\addtotoc{toc}{\contentsline{}{}{}}` does not work is that `hyperref` adds a 4th argument to `\contentsline`, for the hyper anchor.

The macro

```
\newcommand{\adddescriptivetexttotoc}[2][part]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{#1}{#2}{}{}}
}
```

adds a descriptive text to the ToC as a `part` entry (by default) and omits both page number and the hyper anchor, i.e. the last two brace pairs `{}` are empty.

If `hyperref` isn't loaded, the last empty `{}` pair does no harm there, so no check is needed for `hyperref` being loaded.

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} 

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}


\newcommand{\adddescriptivetexttotoc}[2][part]{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{#1}{#2}{}{}}
}

\addtolength{\cftchapindent}{10pt}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\adddescriptivetexttotoc{\normalsize\textnormal{CHAPTER}}

\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo section}

\chapter{Foo bar chapter}
\section{Foo bar section}


\end{document}
```

[image]