# How to suppress hyperlinks for custom headers in toc but still keep hyperlink for entries and page numbers?

Tags: hyperref, tocloft

I would like to use hyperlinks for page numbers and the appropriate entries in my table of contents, which works great using `\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}` for me. Only problem I have is, that I am trying to divide my entries into different "sections" which represent headers using the `tocloft` package and `\cftaddtitleline`. Each section can contain multiple entries like this:
[image]

For some reason, my headers have a hyperlink aswell which is not desired. I would like to have the **hyperlinks** only for **entries** and **page numbers**, not for the headers. Now I know I can suppress the hyperlink for the headers using `\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}`, but this removes my hyperlinks for the entries aswell. This is not desired, "First entry", "Second entry" and "0.1 Third Entry" should still have a hyperlink.
[image]

This is the desired output, which I was not able to recreate in LaTeX:
[image]

Here's my code. For reusage you will have to create a folder named "folder" containing two different pdf-files named "file1.pdf" and "file2.pdf" in the local directory where your tex-file is stored. Or you can of course just use `\section` instead of `\includepdf` (and of course remove the appropriate arguments).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} % notice this is a KOMA-script class

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    % Dummy Page
    \chapter*{Dummy Page}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
    
    % Table of contents linking to pdfs
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Assign the TOC entries to different sections of TOC
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{First section of table of content}{}    
    \includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={
        1,addsec,1,First entry,p1}]{folder/file1.pdf}
    
    
    \cftaddtitleline{toc}{part}{Second section of table of content}{}   
    \includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={
        1,addsec,1,Second entry,p1}]{folder/file2.pdf}
    
    \section{Third entry}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem based on this answer here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301490/206040

This is the new complete code using `\addtocontents` and `\contentsline` before `hyperref` transforms them to make hyperlinks possible. For the headers I've created a new command called `\tocheader` which can be given the header name as an argument. Also this solution does not require the usage of the `tocloft` package anymore.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} % notice this is a KOMA-script class

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\let\origcontentsline\contentsline
\let\origaddtocontents\addtocontents
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\tocheader}[1]{\origaddtocontents{toc}{\protect\origcontentsline{chapter}{#1}{}}}

\begin{document}
    
    % Dummy Page
    \chapter*{Dummy Page}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
    
    % Table of contents linking to pdfs
    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents
    
    % Assign the TOC entries to different sections of TOC
    \tocheader{First section of table of content}
    \includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={
        1,addsec,1,First entry,p1}]{folder/file1.pdf}
    
    
    \tocheader{Second section of table of content}
    \includepdf[pages=-, addtotoc={
        1,addsec,1,Second entry,p1}]{folder/file2.pdf}
    
    \section{Third entry}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus.
    
\end{document}
```

The output now looks just like I've wanted it to look like:

[image]